# question include exception handling with finding of largest and smallest no. this is a assignment problem of coursera platform

Tags: python

question:
Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore  it.

Input:

```
7 ,2 , bob, 10, 4, done.
```

Desired output:

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

Actual output:

```
Invalid input
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

Code:

```
largest=-1
smallest=None
while True:
    num =input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        if num == "done" :
            break
        elif smallest is None:
            smallest=int(num)
        elif int(num)<smallest:
            smallest=int(num)
        elif int(num)>largest:
            largest=int(num)    
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
print("Maximum is",largest) 
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a more Pythonic way of doing this. Try this:

```
inputList = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    try:
        num = int(num)
        inputList.append(num)
    except:
        if num == "done":
            break
        else:
            print ("Invalid input. Ignoring...")
print ("Maximum is:",max(inputList))
print ("Minimum is:",min(inputList))
```

Edit: This code works with Python3. For Python2, you might want to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Answer (score 0):

You are already capturing the `ValueError` in `Exception`, 
So inside, `try`, you are raising `ValueError` there you leave the scope for this error.
When you accept input, and it accepts `4` as input, which is neither larger than `largest` (i.e. 10) nor smaller than the `smallest` (i.e. 2). So it lands in `else` part and raises `ValueError` (as per your code). Hence prints `Invalid input` twice in your case. So this part is unnecessary as well as makes your solution bogus.

Again, from efficiency point of view -

1 - You are checking `smallest == None` for every input, which takes O(1) time and is unnecessary if you take it any integer

Here is the solution you are looking for :-

```
largest=None
smallest=None
while True:

    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        num = int(num)
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
        if largest is None:
            largest = num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        elif num > largest:
            largest = num    

    except ValueError:
        if num == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
print("Maximum is",largest) 
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Comment: As the original code, this solution fails if only *one* number is entered.

Comment: @amain would you mind elaborating what failure are you seeing? I tested with several inputs and I didn't see any failure.    This is a sample input `[7 ,2 , 'bob', 10, 1, -9, 49, 'done']`

Comment: When the input is `[7, 'done']`, your code reports *Max=7, Min=0*, but it should be *Max=7, Min=7*. Using a list as proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61735379/104707) solves that elegantly.